# Fastest way to refer to a dictionary in a list by a value in it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as an input:

```
listOfOptions = [
    {"name": "a", "selected": False},
    {"name": "b", "selected": False}
]
```

I need to change the `"selected"` field from `False` to `True` in any one of these dictionaries, then return it. I understand it would make far more sense for this object to be a dictionary of dictionaries with the keys of each dictionary being the `"name"` field, however, I do not control this input, and cannot change the schema of the output.

This is for a search engine and I am aiming for the quickest responses possible, so looping over a multiple lists of 100+ values to find the right dictionary can be quite time consuming.

Right now, the best way I can think of doing this, is to keep a record of the index of each dictionary, so I can use that to call a specific dictionary in the list. Like this:

```
indexsOfOptions = {"<name>": <indexOfDictionary>, etc...}
listOfOptions[indexsOfOptions["<name>"]]["selected"] = True
```

I really do not like this approach as it just seems like a cheap hack, and can go very wrong if the order of the list changes somehow.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: just iterate over list

Comment: @Mayur I mentioned this. Yeah I can do this but it increases the response time considerably. I know how to do this slow. I am just trying to figure out if there is a way to do this nicely, and with at least similar speed to how this could be done with the 'options' being a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: you have only one selected field to change or more ?

Comment: it sounds better way to make `listOfOptions` as dict like
`listOfOptions = { "a": {"name": "a", "selected": False}, "b": {"name": "b", "selected": False} }`

Comment: @kedarrac only have to change the single 'selected' field in any 1 of the many dictionaries.

Comment: @Mayur yeah I mentioned that too. I can't change the schema for the input/output response. I have requested for this to changed like that, but even if the schema does get changed, it will be some time, and I will still need to do this for backwards compatibility.

Comment: aside from the comment where you mention maintaining an index that corresponds to the entry in the list there is no other quick way to achieve this simply because of the data structure that is being used here to store the data

Comment: One way or the other, the contents of the dictionaries has to be examined. This can be done "on the fly" or via pre-compiled look-up tables containing every possibility and are computed in advance. Both approaches take time, and whether one or the is "best" will depend on how often it need to be used and possibly how memory is consumed to store all the look-up tables. Doing it dynamically would, on the average, only require the content of half of the dictionaries to be examined.

Comment: Have you thought of using only built-in functions that would do the looping internally (i.e. in C) rather than using Python loop?  An example would be to use the filter function  to find the right dictionary (based upon the name key) whose value needs to be changed.

Comment: @DarryIG Ok, thanks. I am going to give this a go, and see how it compares.

Comment: @DarrylG meh, `filter` isn't particularly more performant than a straight-forward loop.

Comment: @martineau Ok. I am going to test out 3 solutions, using a look-up table (I am thinking of just using a dict for this), just iterating over it with a for loop, and then using a built-in (C) function like someone mentioned. I'll compare the time differences and see which is worth it. Cheers.

Comment: @maxharrison your best option is to go with your index approach. Nothing will beat that in terms of speed, and making an index isn't really a hack, it's how you make things performant in general.

Comment: @maxharrison dude, it's going to be no contest. Go with the lookup table. If you wrap the loop in a function, then it will be practically as performant (or better) than `filter`.

Comment: @DarrylG in fact, testing it on a list of 2,000,000 the for-loop is over twice as fast

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga--true and checks with my simulation of various methods that I posted in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tried various method as follows.

```
def _next(lst, name):
  " Search through list for ditionary, and update selected "
  d = next((d for d in lst if d["name"] == name), None)
  if d:
    d['selected'] = True

def _filter(lst, name):
  " Filter list based upon name field of dictionary"
  filtered = filter(lambda d: d['name'] == name, lst)
  d = next(filtered, None)
  if d:
    d['selected'] = True

def _map(lst, name):
  " Map each dictionary to its name field, then find index  "
  mapped = list(map(lambda d: d['name'], lst))
  try:
    i = mapped.index(name)
    d = lst[i]
    d['selected'] = True
  except err:
    pass

def _for_loop(lst, name):
  " Using for loop to find dictionary "
  for d in lst:
    if d['name'] == name:
      d['selected'] = True
      break
```

**Result**

Using a list of 2 million elements, each a dictionary

_next (Generator) and for_loop had the best and comparable times.  They are similar except _next uses a generator (so more space-efficient than for-loop).

> 1. _next (Search through list, and update selected)
>
> 15.9 ms ± 456 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> 2. filter-Filter list based upon name field of dictionary
>
> 35.9 ms ± 2.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>
> 3. map - Map each dictionary to its name field, then find index
>
> 43.1 ms ± 3.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) for_loop
>
> 4. _for_loop--Uses for loop to find dictionary in list
>
> 15.8 ms ± 500 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

**Test Code**

```
N = 2000000
names = ['next', 'filter', 'map', 'for_loop']
for i, func in enumerate([_next, _filter, _map, _for_loop]):
  # Regenerates list since a field is set each time (probably unnecessary)
  alist = [{'name': str(x), "selected": False} for x in range(N)]

  print(names[i])
  %timeit func(alist, str(N-1))  # find the last item in list
```

**Worse Case Test (with identical keys)**

Test with 2 million identical keys.

Primarily recheck with 2 changes:
(1) Recheck filter and for_loop functions since these are the easier to have with multiple identical keys
(2) Remove early break when key is found

New functions

```
def _filter(lst, name):
  " Filter list based upon name field of dictionary"
  filtered = filter(lambda d: d['name'] == name, lst)
  for d in list(filtered):
    d['selected'] = True

def _for_loop(lst, name):
  " Using for loop to find dictionary "
  for d in lst:
    if d['name'] == name:
      d['selected'] = True
```

**Test Code**

```
names = ['filter', 'for_loop']
for i, func in enumerate([_filter, _for_loop]):
  alist = [{'name': str(1), "selected": False} for x in range(N)]

  print(names[i])
  %timeit func(alist, str(1))  # set found items in list
```

**Results**

Pretty similar results as previous test.

```
filter
36 ms ± 3.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
for_loop
15.8 ms ± 780 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Are you sure there is only one dict with the wanted key?

Comment: @kederrac--since my timing tests are for the key at the end of the list the timing results won't change even if there are multiple dicts with the same key.  But, as a matter of implementation, we would change the code so it did not break out of its loops in the case of expecting multiple key hits.

Comment: But your tests are not relevant since the code make sense only if the wanted key is one and is at the end

Comment: You can test for the worst case scenario if you want

Comment: @kederrac--I'm providing a comparison of the worst-case times (which is common for algorithm comparison).  If the key is, for instance, are at the beginning of the list (best case) then the times are comparable.

Comment: You do not have the worst case scenario first of all

Comment: Second, all your functions are bad implemented for multi dict selection

Comment: @kederrac--ok, I could be incorrect about worst-case and all my functions could be "bad implementations".  Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Worst case scenario will be when all the dicts are the same and you have to change all of them

Comment: Since all your functions are looking for only one value to modify will fail for any multi dict scenario

Comment: And I m not saying that are bad implementations, only for multi dict scenario

Comment: @kederrac--thanks for the upvote.  See my extended test that I performed.  There was no difference in the result for filter and for_loop over the previous test.  This would be expected sin if we assume most of the time is consumed tranversing the list rather than assigning a dicitonary value to True.

Comment: Much better IMO

Comment: The OP says *"I need to change the "selected" field from False to True in any **one** of these dictionaries"* (emphasis mine), and in the comments the OP said *"@kederrac only have to change the single 'selected' field in any 1 of the many dictionaries"*.

Comment: @kaya3--thanks.  We see the worst-case timing is the same for changing one or multiple fields.  However, the average time is 1/2 the worst-case timing if we only have to find and change a single dictionary (i.e. half since the average location is in the middle).

Comment: `for d in list(filtered)` doesn't make sense, could just be `for d in filtered`.

Answer (score 1):

here is an O(n) time complexity solution and I do not think it can be any other solution better in terms of time complexity because you have to iterate over the entire list:

```
selected_name = 'a' # just for the example the value is a
for d in listOfOptions:
    if d['name'] == selected_name:
        d['selected'] = True

print(listOfOptions)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'a', 'selected': True}, {'name': 'b', 'selected': False}]
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer since when all is said and one it provides the best timing of the various algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

> *Right now, the best way I can think of doing this, is to keep a record of the index of each dictionary ... can go very wrong if the order of the list changes somehow.*

I think this means the keys will *usually* be at the same index they were on the previous query for the same key, but the index for a given key isn't guaranteed to be constant. In this case you could cache the last index each key was found out, but test whether the cached index is still valid the next time that key is queried. If it is, then you don't need to search; if it isn't, you can do the search again.

If the cached index is no longer valid but the new index is likely to be close to the cached index, you could do a "two-way" linear search starting at the cached index. Basically, initialise `i = cached_index - 1` and `j = cached_index + 1`, then search with `i` decrementing and `j` incrementing.

If the keys are in alphabetical order in the list (as they are in your example) then you can do a binary search instead of a linear search.

All of that said, it's worth benchmarking these solutions, because the fastest way of doing something in Python is often to let the built-in functions/methods which are implemented in C do as much of the work as possible, even if they are theoretically slower according to big O notation.

Comment: Another idea to do before a re-search: Let's say the key was at index 900 before. Now it's not there, instead there's key2 now. Look up where key2 was before. Let's say it was at index 897 before. Then key might have a good chance to be at index 903 now.

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfOptions = [
    {"name": "a", "selected": False},
    {"name": "b", "selected": False}
]

def change(x):
     [i.update({'selected':True}) for i in listOfOptions if i['name'] is x]
```

A generator would be the fastest way I can think of.  I added it to a method that takes a string value to update something with one of your keys.